# Is the bash double bracket conditional expression without operators, specified/documented anywhere?

Tags: bash

`[[ $VAR ]]` appears to be equivalent to `[[ -n $VAR ]]`

The bash manual says:

> [Expressions may be unary or binary](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

which implies an operator is required, but it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're listed as equivalent in the **Conditional Expressions** section of the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> *string*
> **-n** *string*
>     True if the length of *string* is non-zero.

This is also implied by the [POSIX spec for the `test` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128) (which is equivalent to `[ ]`, which the `[[ ]]` syntax is based on):

> In the following list, $1, $2, $3, and $4 represent the arguments presented to *test*:
>
> 0 arguments:
>     Exit false (1).
> 1 argument:
>     Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.

Therefore `[ ]` and `[ '' ]` exit with false/failure status, but `[ something_nonblank ]` exits with true/success status.